# PHP MySQL Query With Linking Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to ask you about Friend Suggestions facebook like.

I have 2 table, that's : tb_user and tb_friend.

tb_user

```
uid | username | full_name
1   | dean     | Dean Cool
2   | ryanblk  | Ryan Black
3   | maria    | Maria Bellen
4   | greg     | Greg Munch
```

tb_friend

```
friend_one_id | friend_two_id | status
1             | 2             | 1
1             | 4             | 1
3             | 4             | 1
```

For status :
1 --> Friend

Now I want to query tb_user linking with tb_friend. Condition, if never friend (Status is not 1) then show it into suggestions friend.

My SQL query so far :

```
$uid --> my session

SELECT 
    U.uid, U.username, U.full_name FROM tb_user U 
WHERE 
    U.uid != '$uid' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

Please help!

Comment: Hm, i think you have to use join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar scenario where i used this as query string

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM friend_table,user_table
WHERE ((from_id = '".$_SESSION['logged_user_id']."' AND friend_table.to_id = user_table.user_id)
              OR 
           (to_id = '".$_SESSION['logged_user_id']."' AND friend_table.from_id = user_table.user_id))
           AND 
             friend_table.status <> '1'";
```

I am editing my db_structure so that you understand

```
[WAIT TILL I GIVE DB STRUCTURE SO THAT YOU UNDERSTAND. I AM EDITING THE ANSWER]
```

My db struture was like this

```
user_table

|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|   user_id    |   username  |    first_name  |  last_name    |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|     1        |   smruti    |     Smruti     |    Singh      |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|     2        |   sunaina   |    Sunaina     |    Singh      |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
```

my friend_table to store the realtion between friends

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
| relation_id  |   from_id   |    to_id       |    status     |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|     1        |      1      |       2        |      1        |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|     2        |      3      |       4        |      0        |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
```

EDIT

This wil show all the result of users who are not your friend.

Keep one thing in mind, if you sent a request to someone then a row is inserted into the friend_table with status 0. If he/she accepts, the status becomes 1. If he/she rejects, the staus becomes 2. If status is 2, you can again send request to him/her.

So here the user_id who are either present in friend_table with status not equal  to 1, or who are not present at all.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE user_id NOT IN 
                  (
                       SELECT user_id FROM friend_table,user_table
                        WHERE ((from_id = '".$_SESSION['logged_user_id']."' AND    
                                 friend_table.to_id = user_table.user_id)
                                      OR 
                               (to_id = '".$_SESSION['logged_user_id']."' AND 
                                 friend_table.from_id = user_table.user_id))
                               AND 
                                  friend_table.status = '1')";
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. But I want first get data from tb_user then check it into tb_friend. If friend so do not need to show it

Comment: since it solved your proble, kindly upvote my answer. I will be grateful

Comment: Welcome.. One thing, keep in mind about what i said about friend status. Cause that way you can keep track of rejected freind requests